# App Engine: What is the best way to store >1MB of text?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, nosql

I would like to store >1MB of text in App Engine NDB but NDB has a 1MB limit on entity size. How else could I store 1 MB of unicode text?

Comment: Hard to say what's *best*, without any details of your intended use, but stashing the large blob in Cloud Storage (or perhaps Cloud SQL) and only a URL or ID in the datastore, is certainly a lively possibility.

Comment: As @AlexMartelli suggested, but with additional meta-data stored in datastore, so you can use datastore for querying, filtering, browsing the entries (maybe with an excerpt of the text?). You could use the datastore entries for access control, too, if you already have something in place and don't want to fiddle with GCS permissions. If you want to provide some kind of text search feature to your users, you could use Search API documents (either alternatively or additionally).

Answer (score 1):

I do this quite a bit.  Initially, I stored the text files in Google Cloud Storage and stored the address of the file in my entity.  I stopped doing this, however, because I found the API for Google Cloud Storage to be too unreliable.  A significant percentage of my requests to store/retrieve files would timeout and continue to timeout on retries (and my files are not that big, most are under 1MB).

To find a better solution, I switched to using NDB compressed properties.  My text files are quite compressible so just about all of mine should be well under the 1MB limit when compressed.  To make it easier, I created a custom property (see below).

My custom property depends from a compressed `ndb.BlobProperty` and I just add encoding and decoding to UTF8.  At some point, I will further expand this to store the text in Google Cloud Storage when the input text exceeds a size threshold.

If you expect your compressed text to be under the 1MB limit then this would be a good solution for you.  Otherwise, you should use the [GCS Python Client](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) but watch out for timeout errors.

```
class UTF8BlobProperty(ndb.BlobProperty):
    """
    This is a custom blob property for storing unicode text as utf-8.
    Later, we can add storing to GCS if text is too large.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(UTF8BlobProperty, self).__init__(default="", compressed=True)

    def _validate(self, text):
        if not isinstance(text, basestring):
            raise TypeError("Expected a basestring, got %s" % text)

    def _to_base_type(self, text):
        return text.encode("utf-8")

    def _from_base_type(self, text):
        return text.decode("utf-8")
```